# How to get user's information when registering or logging in via ajax form

Tags: ajax, craft-pro

I did search for this but was unable to find the documentation for getting user's data on a return when logging them in from a front-end facing login form (I need to do the same for a registration as well).

I need to get a return of the user's Id and their email.

This is my code for the form. It works fine,  I just cannot seem to find the user's info in the data return so if anyone has an example or suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#workshop-registration-user-login-form').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('#workshop-registration-user-login-form').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/users/login',
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data.currentUserId);

    ...

    // get data populate the fields
  })
  .error(function(data) {
    console.log('error');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what other user info you're looking for, but Craft's [UsersController](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController) will only return [two things](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/controllers/UsersController.php#L1601-L1608) in the JSON response of a successful login for an AJAX request.

A `success` key set to `true` and a `returnUrl` key set to where the login redirect should go to.

Comment: so no way to get user Id and email?

Comment: You'd want to do an additional controller call upon successful login to get info about the currently-logged in user, with your own controller to return that info, if that is what you need.

Comment: O.k., so I need to create my own controller for this?

Comment: You could also just ajax load in a Craft template with `currentUser.id` and `currentUser.email` in it, in your success handler - if you want to avoid a controller for whatever reason.  But a controller for this would be trivial really.

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand your question correctly what you are trying to achieve is to get used data of a user that is trying to log in.

Craft's login controller will call the userSessionService->login() method which in turn will call the loginByUserId method. This method has two events attached to it - the onBeforeLogin and the onLogin.

-- onBeforeLogin is called before anything is really created.
-- onLogin is called if the login was succesfull.

Now if you listed to the onLogin method you get the param username. Craft will already have validated this username and logged it in - so you know it is good. You can then call

`craft()->users->getUserByUsernameOrEmail($yourUsernameVar);`

Which will return a populated UserModel. Hope it helps in some way

Answer (score -2):

In your case, i think you can use [element-api](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api), this is a great plugin for extracting data through ajax.

Comment: This is really too general a response, and not an answer to the user's question as such.